# mySQL query get only after a particular timestamp time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sensor that writes data to an SQL table, namely the timestamp and the value (say temperature).

I need a way to execute SQL in PHP so I can print ONLY the values for say today, or a date Jan 21st. You need not post code. I just need to know how to approach this please.

I have seen code like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2012-05-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-05 23:59:59'
```

I have no idea how to use this in PHP, and what it will return. Can anyone provide some assistance?

Comment: Well have you googled '*PHP + MySQL*?'.  You should be looking at [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Specifically: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://php.net/mktime and http://php.net/date you can combine both like

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2006));`